# Check if multiple lists contain multiple items

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists in my python code, and I want to check if *any* of those lists contains a certain two items.

```
f1=['a','b']
f2=['c','d']
f3=['e','f']
f4=['g','h']
f5=['i','j']
f6=['k','l']

flist=[f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6]
```

I want something like:

```
if 'a' in flist[0:5] and 'b' in flist[flist.index('a')]:
   print (true)
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: why not just iterate over `flist` and do the check on every list in there?

Comment: So, you want to find out which lists contain both items?

Comment: you can just iterate over `flist` and get the index of the list which has both elements.

Comment: i have added an answer, as it was too big for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for f in flist:
    if 'a' not in f:
        continue
    if 'b' not in f:
        continue
    return True
return False
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried something similar before but it wasn't working, this is good.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with `issubset`:

```
if any({'a', 'b'}.issubset(sublist) for sublist in flist):
    print "a and b were found"
```

By using `any`, the search is called off as soon as a *superset* of the search items is found.

This handles the general case where the sublists may contain more than two items.

---

But if the *sublists* will always contain two items, it is sufficient to check for equality:

```
if any({'a', 'b'} == set(sublist) for sublist in flist):
    print "a and b were found"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you just iterate over it.

```
for i in range(len(flist)):
  if ['a', 'b'] == sorted(flist[i]):
    print (i)
```

or you can simply do one-liner, just to know if it exists.

```
print (["a", "b"] in [sorted(x) for x in flist])
```

Comment: Use `for sublist in flist` instead of `for i in range(len(flist))`.

Comment: that was if it existed then print the index of that list.

Comment: If you want the keep the index then `for i,sublist in enumerate(flist)` is the way to go.

Comment: That's true, just not a habit yet. I'll surely use `enumerate` more. Thank you!!